# Javascript Object Remove Key based on Value Keep Object

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck on this awhile. Found a lot of example on how to remove based on key, but not on value.

I am trying to remove all keys that have value false.

Any help would be appreciated,  It seems Object.keys only accesses keys, val seems to have no effect.

```js
const names = {
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  5: false
}

const newNames = Object.keys(names).reduce((object, key, val) => {
  console.info('propName', key);
  if (object[val] == true) {
    object[key] = names[key];
  }
  return object;
}, {});
console.info('test', newNames);
// expected output I want should be  {2:true, 3:true}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking `names[key]` is `true`

```js
const names = {
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  5: false
}

const newNames = Object.keys(names).reduce((object, key, val) => {
  if (names[key]) {
    object[key] = names[key];
  }
  return object;
}, {});

console.info('test', newNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to modify the object itself, you event don't need to declare a new object. use `delete`

```
const names = {
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  5: false
}
for (let k in names){if(!names[k]){delete names[k]}}
console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = {
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  5: false
}

for(let name of Object.keys(names)) {
    if(names[name] === false) {
        delete names[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(names).map(val => {  if(names[val] == false) { delete names[val] } });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.